# Is there a way to set APPL_NAME on the DB2 Connection externally instead of "db2jcc_application" (e.g. with System Property)

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I am using a Java application that connects to DB2 over JDBC. It creates the connection such that the application name (sysibmadm.applications -> APPL_NAME) remains the JDBC default "db2jcc_application". Is there a way to **externally** set the APPL_NAME to a desired value? (e.g. in Oracle, I can pass `-Doracle.jdbc.v$session.program=MyApplName` to have a similar effect).

I want to do this so that I can clearly identify all the connections coming into my DB2. Currently all the java applications show up as "db2jcc_application".

I wrote a small piece of code to illustrate this ...

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class DB2ApplName {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InterruptedException {
        Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");

        Properties connProps = new Properties();
        connProps.put("user", "<my db2 user>");
        connProps.put("password", "<my db2 password>");

        // Create a connection **WITHOUT** Application Name
        Connection connWithoutApplName = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://<ip>:<port>/<dbname>",
                                                                     connProps);

        // Add Application Name to the properties
        connProps.put("clientProgramName", "MyApplName");
        // Create a connection **WITH** Application Name
        Connection connWithApplName = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://<ip>:<port>/<dbname>",
                                                                  connProps);
        System.out.println("Sleeping for 60 seconds - check the connections.");
        Thread.sleep(60000L); // During this time I will run query on DB2 to see connection details.

        connWithoutApplName.close();
        connWithApplName.close();
    }
}
```

This code creates two connections, one **wihtout** ApplName set and one **with** ApplName set.

When the code is in `Thread.sleep`, I query the db ...

```
select appl_name from sysibmadm.applications
where client_nname = '<my client ip>' with ur;

APPL_NAME         
------------------
db2jcc_application
MyApplName
```

As you can see the second connection has the application name correctly stamped, but the first connection simply has "db2jcc_application" as its name. But, of course, I could do this only if I could modify the application code - which I cannot.

The second way I found I can do this is by setting the JDBC URL in the application settings/properties in a particular fashion. Instead of simply using `JDBCURL=jdbc:db2://<ip>:<port>/<dbname>` in the application settings, if I set `JDBCURL=jdbc:db2://<ip>:<port>/<dbname>:clientProgramName=MyApplName;`, then the application name gets stamped correctly. Unfortunately, for certain applications that we have, we need to start multiple JVM processes, but I cannot set the above mentioned setting separately for each of these processes. I can set JVM parameters (such as `-D` parameters) separately for each process.

Thus, I am looking to see if there is a way to **externally** pass the Application Name so that the JDBC Driver will pick it up and stamp it on the connection.

Comment: Wouldn't that be an environment variable or command parameter that your program needs to pick up and pass on to JDBC?

Comment: @data_henrik, I only wrote the sample program to illustrate the point. The applications in the ecosystem are not written by us. They are third party apps. I don't have their code and thus cannot touch the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the list of available properties, which can be set via a JVM parameter or a properties file:
[IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ configuration properties](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052075.html).
According to this link, you are **not able** to set the `clientProgramName` property in such a way.

Comment: thanks a lot. I am confused about a couple of things in the link ... where are these "configuration properties" to be set. I guess, if you are in the context of WAS, you might have a place to set those when you configure the data source, but if you are running a stand-alone JVM, where would you set that? I will try to take a look around to see if I can get more info on that myself, but if you know off hand, please do reply with that info. It would be of great help.

Comment: Also, I am confused why this link doesn't show ```clientProgramName```. See [this another link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/wcs/entry/Admin_Tip_Name_your_DB2_Connections?lang=en), where it talks about how ```clientProgramName``` can be set on data source property.  (Sorry, I had to break my comment into two parts)

Comment: As stated at the [Customization of IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ configuration properties](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_cjvcfgpr.html) link, you can set these configuration properties either in the resource file `DB2JccConfiguration.properties`, which has to be in your `CLASSPATH`, or specify such a file with an arbitrary name in the `-Ddb2.jcc.propertiesFile` JVM parameter. Unfortunately, not all possible jdbc properties can be “externally” set in such a way.

Comment: Thanks. That link explains multiple ways of setting the properties, including as system properties. I could actually set ```-Ddb2.jcc.currentSchema=<mySchema>``` successfully. Alas, as you mentioned, ```clientProgramName``` cannot be set.

Comment: Marking this answer as solution - even though it didn't *solve* my problem, it definitely *took it to closure*.